# Initializing a Collection View with a XIB -- "layout object must be non-nill"

Tags: xcode, collectionview

I have seen a similar question asked here about creating collection views programmatically but not with IB or nibs or xibs or whatever I am supposed to call it.

Its my understanding that when using a XIB the objects inside the XIB get instantiated automatically by IB.  Therefore, it makes sense that for another collectionView I am creating with a XIB it works without programmatically instantiating a flow layout object.  However, this second view is crashing with the error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

My first thought was to alloc/init a new flow layout and add it to the collectionViews layout object as in `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = newLayout`.  (I'm in a collection View Controller).  However, this property seems to be read-only.  Because I'm using a XIB I assume xcode is somehow doing the layout behind the scenes but that doesn't help with figuring out whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> My first thought was to alloc/init a new flow layout and add it to the collectionViews layout object

Probably the opposite order: first initialize the FlowLayout instance then initialize the CollectionView with frame and layout

Comment: but the collection view is being initialized by the xib.  If i go to set the layout property of the collection view in the viewDidLoad of my collectionView controller it is read-only.

Comment: the documentation definitely says that a CollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil FlowLayout. Either create both objects in IB or both programatically

Comment: i have two view controllers both with a XIB file.  The parent view controller launches fine but the child view crashes because of a nill layout.  I've checked every page in the utilities and both XIBs are identical.  Somehow the working view controller's XIB is properly setting up a layout and the child view controller isn't.  Running a project level search for "layout" yields no results so I know the layouts are being instantiated and added to the collection views behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this I think I've got the solution. Assuming you have a collection view layout set in your XIB, I've confirmed with Apple that there is a bug with calling `UICollectionViewController.init()` and `UICollectionViewController.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` that causes the collection view's layout to not be set.

Workaround:

To work around this use `UICollectionViewController.init(nibName: "NameOfMyXIB", bundle: nil)` and it will appropriately set the collection view's layout.